# Convert array of uint8_t into array of uint16_t (ASCII to Unicode)

Tags: c, unicode, ascii

I have a `uint8_t` array of size n>1 and would like to cast it into a `uint16_t` array of the same size n>1. I actually use the `uint8_t` array for ASCII characters and would like to use now UNICODE.

Any ideas how this conversion can be done?

Edit: 
I would like to use this function here, which works fine for const char *string as argument and not for `const uint16_t *string`. So somehow I need to cast it.

```
srv_err_t gui_write_text_16bit(const uint16_t *string, Layout_type_t layout,
    Layout_field_t field, Text_inverted_t inv) {
  srv_err_t err;
  uint8_t charCount;
  uint8_t byteCount;
  uint16_t bitmapCol = 0;
  uint16_t bitmapRow = 0;
  uint8_t textLength = 0;
  uint8_t textHeight = GUI_FONT_NAME.FontHeight;

  uint16_t offset;
  uint8_t mask;

  lcd_rectangle_t position;

  if (LAYOUT_A == layout) {
    if (LAYOUT_FIELD6 == field) {
      // Position 6 is not available in Layout A
      err.bits.input_parameter = true;
      return err;
    }
  }

  GUI_CONST_STORAGE GUI_CHARINFO
  *pcharInfo;
  GUI_CONST_STORAGE
  unsigned char* pchar;
  GUI_CONST_STORAGE GUI_FONT_PROP
  *pfontProp;

  //uint8_t textBitmap [bitmapLength * textHeight];
  uint8_t textBitmap[(LCD_COLUMN_NUMBER_DISPLAY / 8) * GUI_FONT_HEIGHT] = { 0 };

  /* Calculate needed space in the array */
  //      for (charCount = 0; charCount < stringLength; charCount++)
  for (charCount = 0; string[charCount] != '\0'; charCount++) {
    pfontProp = GUI_FONT_NAME.FontProp;

    while (0 != pfontProp) {
      if (pfontProp->First <= string[charCount]
          && pfontProp->Last >= string[charCount]) {
        offset = string[charCount] - pfontProp->First;
        pcharInfo = (pfontProp->pCharInfoFirstChar) + offset; // Pointer to the right character

        textLength += pcharInfo->XSize; // Text length in Pixels
        break; // exit while loop and beginn with next character
      }

      pfontProp = pfontProp->pNext;
    }
  }

  textLength = (textLength / 8) + 1;        // Text length in Bytes

  //      for(charCount = 0; charCount < stringLength; charCount++)

  for (charCount = 0; string[charCount] != '\0'; charCount++) {
    pfontProp = GUI_FONT_NAME.FontProp;

    while (0 != pfontProp) {
      if (pfontProp->First <= string[charCount]
          && pfontProp->Last >= string[charCount]) {
        // Character in Range found
        offset = string[charCount] - pfontProp->First;
        pcharInfo = (pfontProp->pCharInfoFirstChar) + offset; // Pointer to the right character
        pchar = pcharInfo->pData;

        for (bitmapRow = 0; bitmapRow < textHeight; bitmapRow++) {
          uint16_t bitmapByte = 0;
          uint16_t charByte = 0;
          uint8_t pixelShift;
          for (byteCount = 0; byteCount < pcharInfo->BytesPerLine;
              byteCount++) {
            //bitmapByte = bitmapRow * bitmapLength + (bitmapCol / 8) + byteCount;
            bitmapByte = bitmapRow * textLength + (bitmapCol / 8) + byteCount;
            charByte = pcharInfo->BytesPerLine * bitmapRow + byteCount;
            pixelShift = bitmapCol % 8;

            if (byteCount == (pcharInfo->BytesPerLine - 1)) {
              // Last Byte in row

              switch (pcharInfo->XSize % 8) {
                case 1:
                  mask = 0x80;
                  break;
                case 2:
                  mask = 0xC0;
                  break;
                case 3:
                  mask = 0xE0;
                  break;
                case 4:
                  mask = 0xF0;
                  break;
                case 5:
                  mask = 0xF8;
                  break;
                case 6:
                  mask = 0xFC;
                  break;
                case 7:
                  mask = 0xFE;
                  break;
                case 0:
                  mask = 0xFF;
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
              }
              textBitmap[bitmapByte] |= (pchar[charByte] & mask) >> pixelShift;
              textBitmap[bitmapByte + 1] |= (pchar[charByte] & mask)
                  << (8 - pixelShift);
              //bitmapCol += pcharInfo->XSize % 8;
            } else {

              /* charByte is not aligned with the bitmapByte. A direct copy is not possible */
              textBitmap[bitmapByte] |= pchar[charByte] >> pixelShift;

              textBitmap[bitmapByte + 1] |= pchar[charByte]
                  << (8 - pixelShift);

            }

          }
        }
        bitmapCol += pcharInfo->XSize;

        break; // exit while loop and beginn with next character
      }
      pfontProp = pfontProp->pNext;
    }
  }

  if (layout == LAYOUT_A) {
    position = Layout_A_Text_Field[field];

    /* place Bitmap on the right display Position */
    if (LAYOUT_TITLE == field) {
      gui_place_text(&position, textLength, textHeight, ALIGN_CENTER);
    } else {
      gui_place_text(&position, textLength, textHeight, ALIGN_LEFT);
    }

    if (LAYOUT_FIELD2 == field) {
      lcd_draw_text(position, textBitmap, sizeof(textBitmap),
          Layout_A_Field[field], DRAW_INVERSE);
    } else {
      lcd_draw_text(position, textBitmap, sizeof(textBitmap),
          Layout_A_Field[field], DRAW_NORMAL);
    }
  }
  return err;
}
```

Comment: do you have an existing piece of code to show ?

Comment: If you want a string with 16 bit characters, simply casting the array variable is not enough. You need to convert between the encodings, in the simplest case by filling the upper byte with zeros, or just use a function that's meant for this, like `MultiByteToWideChar()` on Windows, or whatever your platform/framework provides.

Comment: You would indeed have to produce a new array of an equal length (length in terms of amount of elements) and copy each element to it while converting. Because currently the array is 8 bits wide for each element and if you'd cast it to an array of 16 bits elements, each element in the 16 bits array use two elements of the 8 bit elements array. A for loop would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Casting would be non sense because each element in a char array uses 1 single byte while 2 are needed for a UNICODE uint16_t array. But provided your initial string is composed of only ASCII or Latin1 characters, you can use the fact the the unicode code point of an ASCII or Latin1 character is just the character value.

So if the resulting array is allocated in caller, you could use code as simple as:

```
// Convert an ASCII or Latin1 string to a 16bits unicode string:
void tounicode(uint16_t *dest, const char *src, size_t nchars) {
    while(nchars-- > 0) {                    // process nchars characters
        *dest++ = (unsigned char) *src++;    // one at a time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using x86 hardware check out the SSE2 routines that convert a 16-byte vector into two 8-element uint16 vectors, in 2 machine ops. _mm_unpacklo_epi8() and ...unpackhi...